# All the components styles in one xml file?

Tags: android, styles, android-drawable

Can we add multiple styles for different components in one xml file in drawable folder?
For example,
Code for one button

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorDarkBlue"/>
</shape>
```

Code for the other button

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPink"/>
</shape>
```

Can we add the both codes in to a single xml file in the drawable folder or should we need to create two separate xml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create separate xml files.

Because [they](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) are referenced by their file names when you use them.

Unlike `string` resources which are referenced by `id's`

Answer (score 1):

> create separately for both buttons

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle" >
     <gradient
        android:angle="180"
         android:centerColor="@color/Bisque"
       android:endColor="@color/colorDarkBlue"
     android:startColor="@color/colorDarkBlue" />
     <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@color/Black" />
     <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
       android:bottom="10dp"
     android:left="10dp"
      android:right="10dp"
     android:top="10dp" />
      </shape>
```